# FIWARE IoT Agent: install from RPMs

Tags: linux, centos7, fiware, iot

We have build FIWARE IoT Agent on centos7 and then we wanted to install thoses RPMs on our instance based on the image: CentOS-7-x64

but we have got the following errors:

```
[centos@mqtt-iot-agent ~]$ sudo rpm -i iot-agent-base-egm42-egmre42.x86_64.rpm 
BDB2053 Freeing read locks for locker 0xa5: 19063/140136414238720
BDB2053 Freeing read locks for locker 0xa7: 19063/140136414238720
[centos@mqtt-iot-agent ~]$ sudo rpm -i iot-agent-mqtt-egm42-egmre42.x86_64.rpm 
BDB2053 Freeing read locks for locker 0xa8: 19683/139977937053696
BDB2053 Freeing read locks for locker 0xaa: 19683/139977937053696
```

Answer (score 0):

Those RPMs were made for Centos6.5.

As long as you are using Centos 7, we strongly recommend you to get to the GIT repository and follow compilation instructions (do not use the development branch but the latest stable one, please).

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-IoTAgent-Cplusplus

In the meanwhile, you may also test our public instance as published here:
  http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/backend-device-management-idas/instances

Thanks for using IDAS!